# Showing a result message on cmd

Tags: cmd

I am trying to show the user a message telling them the result on screen rather than on cmd.

I have tried `msg *` but with the code below it doesn't work for some reason

```
set MyResult= %MyName% %%i && echo %%i && net user %%i /domain | find /I "password last set"
```

I want to show the output of this code on a message box.

the hole code is for a password checker system, it's to check when did the user changed there password.

thank you for your help

Comment: but will it show the result ?

Comment: i'm kinda new to cmd i always thought it was stupid but i'm stuck with it and don't know much about it :D

Comment: no problem, i have posted something for ya. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick workaround...

**MsgBox.bat**

```
@echo off
set tempofile_msgbox=%random%%random%_msgbox.tmp.vbs
echo Msgbox ^"%*^" >%tempofile_msgbox%
wscript.exe //nologo %tempofile_msgbox%
del %tempofile_msgbox%
```

**Usage**

```
MsgBox.bat Hello World!
```